# I want to call a 'function' that calls a 'loop' and I want that loop to break if I call the initial function again

Tags: python, time, sleep

I want to call a function and within that function i want a loop.
However i need it so if i call that same function again during the loop, it breaks the loop.

is this possible?

how can i achieve this?

the reason is: i have a button that plays some midi notes that requires a `time.sleep(1)` to allow the note to play, however during this sleep time i cannot press the button again as the code is in sleep. I want it so i press the button and it does `time.sleep()` however if i press this button again during this sleep i would like it to  interupt the `time.sleep()` and start the function again. I thought the best way to do this was to make a loop of `time.sleep()` in ten 0.1 second increments and if i press the button again at say...0.6 seconds in it will interupt the `time.sleep()` and restart the function playing a new note.

any ideas?

is there an alternative to `time.sleep()` where i can interupt the sleep whenever a function is called?

if this is a badly worded question then i appologie

Comment: You need to use some kind of multi-threading, or maybe a framework like pygame that manages events asynchronously

Comment: I'm actually using pygame for the midi but i'm using time.sleep(1) after every note. I will look into multi threading.

Comment: I'll bet pygame has its own delay method that you should use instead of `sleep()`, and it will allow the wait to be interrupted.

Comment: ah yes you are right! thankyou